# Entity SQL Select Column?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013, entity

I don't know that my SQL syntax wrong or the way I code is wrong. I had use a syntax ObjectQuery hs = new ObjectQuery, but it's won't run so I try to type many way I had found on the internet, so if there are any way to type that esier could you show me, thank first !

http://s15.postimg.org/3zu3683rf/image.png

http://s29.postimg.org/cdtb91m53/image.png

Here my code, It's not notice any error but the data don't display in the grid.

```
string query = "SELECT c.MAHS, c.HOHS FROM HSDATAEntities.HOCSINHs AS c";
ObjectQuery<HOCSINH> hocsinh =((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<HOCSINH>(query);
dataGridView.DataSource = hocsinh.ToList();
```

Comment: broken URL. Can you give the details along with the question itself

Comment: I uploaded new image url, you can see it. Thanks !

Comment: OK, so when you use `SELECT VALUE c FROM...` you get nothing in the grid.  Is that the problem?  Not surprising, since that's not a valid SQL statement.  What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve?  Post some code here that replicates the problem and we might be able to help.

Comment: When I use SELECT VALUE c FROM... the data display in the grid but when I use SELECT c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName FROM... the data don't display. That's a problem I have

Comment: Everybody, can anyone help me to solve this, I've tried a lot but I can't so I have posted this, hope can get answer soon. Thanks !